# How can `gem list` show multiple `default` versions for a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

When I run `gem list bundler`, I get the following result

```
+ gem list bundler
 
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
 
bundler (default: 2.3.22, default: 2.1.4)
```

How is it possible that *two* versions are marked as default? Is there a way to update the default one?

---

##### Context

The reason I ended up looking into which is the default Bundler version is that I've been running into this warning on a self-managed CI machine on and off for a while:

```
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated bundler 2.3.22 [or whichever latest version is available], but your Gemfile requires bundler 2.1.4.
```

I looked into my `Gemfile.lock` and it requires `bundler` like this:

```
bundler (>= 1.12.0, < 3.0.0)
```

So I'm guessing at some point, Bundler activated (which I believe means selected for runtime use) version `2.1.4` because that was the default available one.

I hope to be able to forever prevent that error by forcing the latest version of bundler to be the one used at runtime, but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

That is, how can I get the `gem list bundler` output to not show `default: 2.1.4`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could try removing all versions, then rolling back in the one you want. I've never seen more than one listed as default,  but the internal state could be messed up and a reinstall could set that straight.

Comment: Thank you for your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73967910/how-can-gem-list-show-multiple-default-versions-for-a-gem#comment130603686_73967910 @tadman. Unfortunately it seems like I can't remove default gems... `gem list bundler` gives me `bundler (default: 2.3.22, default: 2.1.4)`. `gem uninstall --force bundler` prints `Gem bundler-2.1.4 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem` and `Gem bundler-2.3.22 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`.
Fetching bundler-2.3.23.gem

Comment: What Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To delete the duplicate default versions

```
gem environment
```

you will find the installation directory:

```
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/seb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
```

in /specifications/default you will find your .gemspec files, you will remove your duplicate one

```
rm bundler-2.2.31.gemspec
```

to verify: `gem list bundler`

```
(2.2.31, 2.2.29, default: 2.2.15)
```

you can update the default version with `gem install bundler:2.3.18 --default` but it appears that bundler use a arbitrary version that fit his needs. If you want use a specific version to bundle the Gemfile, you add it in your gemfile

`gem "bundler", "~> 2.3"`

it will appear at the end of the gemfile.lock

`BUNDLED WITH 2.3.18`